# How do I avoid running into violating unique constraints using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, locking, unique, unique-constraint

I have a database table which has a unique constraint defined on one of its columns. I also have a message processing system with multiple threads. As the messages are being consumed, there could be times where two messages contain the same entity with the same value (the value of the column which has the unique constraint defined). So in the code, service layer first queries the database by using this unique field (via hibernate named query) to see if any records exists first. If not, then it inserts a new record. If a record with this unique field exists already, instead of inserting a record, it updates it and also inserts a child record in another table.

I am running into an issue in which the second thread thinks that the record is not there yet, so it tries to insert it in. However, by this time first thread already successfully inserted the record. So exception gets thrown about violation of the unique constraint. Can you help what is the best way to handle this kind of situation using hibernate/oracle solution? Do I need some sort of lock options? Thanks.

Comment: You state that you want an Oracle/Hibernate solution.  Is there a reason you cannot change your messaging system so it is synchronized?  It sounds like you have coded the way it performs so you might be able to handle it in this fashion much more simply than within Hibernate or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to avoid rollback in this case goes against the spirit of [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (in particular, used by Oracle), since it requires excessive locking.

I think it would be better to react on rollback of insert by starting another transaction to perform update.